# Cannot exclude rows with orwhere in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

The below code doesnt work as I expected. I want all names with science except names like 'science assessment'  How do I exclude the names like 'science assessment' and keep the other rows with names of just science. I have no subject name with the name of just 'science'

```
$subjectScience = $this->Students->Subjects->find('list')
     ->select(['id', 'name'])
     ->where(['Subjects.name not LIKE'  => '%assessment%'])
     ->andWhere(['Subjects.name LIKE'  => '%physics%']) 
     ->orWhere(['Subjects.name LIKE'  => '%chemistry%']) 
     ->orWhere(['Subjects.name LIKE'  => '%biology%']) 
     ->orWhere(['Subjects.name LIKE'  => '%science%','Subjects.name not LIKE'  => '%assessment%'])    //doesnt work as i expect    
     ->order(['Subjects.name' => 'asc']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you exactly want the particular string only then why not to use assignment operator.So try using:

```
'Subjects.name'  => 'science'
```

instead of:

```
'Subjects.name LIKE'  => '%science%'
```

Comment: No this is not what I want.!! The subject name can contain 'science' but the subject name is just the string ;'science'. I cant exclude the rows from the query which contains the words 'science' and  'assessment'

Comment: but your query already seems like you want..can yo post the debug value of $subjectScience ?

Comment: I have a subject called 'science assessment' which I dont want but I have 4 other subjects with science in the name which I want returned. I think the issue is clear enough though.